# Install / run Cabal to ultimately use pandoc

Tags: ghc, cabal, pandoc, haddock

In my search to use pandoc on Unix, I have found out that my SLES11 OS has GHC already installed, and I see that the Cabal package is indeed there. However, the cabal command is not found, so I tried to install cabal. When I run the bootstrapper, it says that Haddock is not found (Haddock.hs does show to be in the Distribution folder, so I don't know why it's not found). This makes me wonder if there is a simple setup command I can use to sort of activate the Cabal package already installed in GHC?? Then once I have that running, I want to use Pandoc, which I have already been using in Windows.

Comment: `Cabal` is a library, it does not provide the `cabal` command. We usually refer to the executable bit as `cabal-install` to disambiguate. Anyway, I would investigate if your OS doesn't already have a package for pandoc. I suspect it does and that it'd be a lot easier for you to just install that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion. I have looked through the list of ghc packages I have, and Cabal is there, but I do not see Pandoc. Would it be listed elsewhere?

Comment: @MateuszKowalczyk, I meant to add this to my previous comment. Just from looking at the pandoc installation page, it seems that I have to install cabal in order to install pandoc. Is this not necessarily true?

Comment: I have installed the pandoc files, but it seems that I still need the cabal executable to get pandoc working.